# Java polymorphism when passing variables.

Tags: java, parameters, polymorphism, parameter-passing, variable-types

```
class X{
    public void print(X x){System.out.println("xx");}
    public void print(Y y){System.out.println("xy");}
}
class Y extends X{
    public void print(X x){System.out.println("yx");}
    public void print(Y y){System.out.println("yy");}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        X x = new Y();
        x.print(x);
        System.out.println(x.getClass());
    }

}
```

The output i get is "yx" end I dont understand why, x.getClass() returns "class Y" so shouldn't its call the method where the parameter is Y?

Comment: Nope, because you boxed Y into X.

Comment: Overloading is resolved at compile time (where `x` is an `X`), not runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloads (i.e. choice which of multiple methods of the same class/interface with the same name to use) are resolved based on static types. This is in opposition to *overriding* (choice between `X#print(X)` and `Y#print(X)` which is resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic binding doesn't work for method parameters, hence parameter resolution of method is done in compile time, and the compiler resolves with the static type `X`.